# Populating lookup fields using an external ID

Tags: apex, salesforce-id

I have an lookup field in my opportunity object which is pointing to a custom object called `Code__c`.

`Code__c` has an external Id field called `Code_Source__c`.

When creating an opportunity once way of linking the opportunity to `Code__c` is by passing Id.

```
Opportunity op = new Opportunity(Name = 'Test Op', StageName = 'Open', ... , Oppoortunity_Code__c =code.Id );
```

Is it possible to use external ID (`Code_Source__c`) instead of the `code.Id`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
//create an in-memory instance of code, with the external id set
Code__c code = new Code__c(Code_Source__c = 'EXTERNAL_ID_HERE');

//create an instance of Opportunity, and point to the instance of code created above
Opportunity op = new Opportunity(Name = 'Test Op', StageName = 'Open', ... , Oppoortunity_Code__r = code );

upsert op;
```

Comment: Can I apply the same concept if I want to use external Id of a standard object. For instance when I am creating Opportunity Team members?

Comment: Yes you can use this for any relationships where there is an External Id, eg relating Contacts to Accounts using an External Id field on Account.

Comment: I tried using this relationship to pull Users and Opportunity while creating Opportunity Team members. But it is returning null.  Following are the two statements:   User teamUser = new User(PeopleSoft_Empl_ID__c = 'Temp12345');  and  Opportunity req = new Opportunity(Requisition_Number__c = 'Req1234');

Comment: @YashMehta is this functionality documented somewhere?